# Populate dropdown without using ViewBag from controller but it could work in asp.net mvc,how does it happen?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my controller, I store my dropdown options in a `ViewBag`:

```
var departments = db.Departments.OrderBy(q => q.Name).ToList();
ViewBag.SelectedDepartments = new SelectList(departments, "DepartmentID", "Name", SelectedDepartment);
```

In view, I know I can populate dropdown list using something like:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedDepartment", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SelectedDepartments,"All")
```

But why below code also works which does not use ViewBag at all, how does `ViewBag` play the role in the situation?

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedDepartments", "All")
```

Comment: That's hard to answer because even Microsoft Documentation says the first string parameter is for the name. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_SelectExtensions_DropDownList_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_

Comment: @ Jerdine Sabio That's what I am curious about since I do not use mode/form in the view...